# Texture Randomly Generated and Sized Rects

Tags: box2d, libgdx, textures, procedural-programming

I'm making a game (libgdx & box2d) with randomly generated planets having skyscrapers on them - see image below.

The Skyscrapers are random in their position, width and height. I'm now looking for the best way to texture these.

This is a general question on how to best solve texturing randomly sized objects, you don't need to supply code, though you may.

What are the options I have? Make small texture-squares and tile them? Stretch them? Procedurally generate them (would this be possible for a skyscraper-like texture - grey square for the base and black/yellow windows for with/without light)? What do I have to consider?

I really don't know how to go about this at the moment. Any ideas are welcome!

Thank you!

Jonas

[image: Planet with Skyscrapers]

Managed to do get it done with stretching - now only using one texture for all sizes, but I'll change that.
[image: stretched textures over box2d objects]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you have alot of possebilitys to solve this. Streching often does not look nice if you are close to those. But if they are fare away it could be a good solution. in my opinion Generating those does take time i guess and thats not a good idea for a game. You even do have to code alot of stuff and they look always simelar i guess.

 I think Tileing isn't possible because your skytower are not always on a base of the tiles. So for example you got 32px Tiles and your tower is 53px high it does not work well because you would need to strech / cut or such one of the tiles.

I'd take the streching solution with a good filter. Get more than 1 picture for that so if you have bigger towers also take a bigger picture for a better solution. You need to take care about the width and height. You shouldnt clinch a really wide tower to much and also should stech a thin tower to a wide one. You can also randomize it a bit so you got some different pictures for sure. 
Example for a Filter:

```
// we set the linear texture filter to improve the stretching
splashTexture.setFilter( TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear );
```

[From this tutorial](http://steigert.blogspot.de/2012/02/2-libgdx-tutorial-game-screens.html)
Also take a look at this entry from the libgdx: [Know Your Texture Filters!](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403)

But this is just my opinion.

---

To find out the Filter is used by default take a look at the `Texture` Methods.

```
getMagFilter();
getMinFilter()
```

because you set the filters like this:

```
setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter minFilter, Texture.TextureFilter magFilter)
```

Comment: Thank you, BennX. You wrote something about stretching with a "good filter". Could you elaborate on what you mean by that? I'm very new to graphics/game programming, so a pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I added a small example. You can sett filter to images so they get scald in diferent ways. With some filter you may get a bad result but with some other it maybe really good. Take a look at the Enum TextureFilter what it does offer.

Comment: Thank you, BennX! I'll check it out tonight!

Comment: Linear is certainly the best filter for stretching, but it comes with a major loss of performance when used extensively. Based on the picture of your game, trying to render all those buildings with a linear filter isn't going to run well on lower-end devices.

Comment: Hey Jyro, thanks for that input. What is the normal filtering that occurs when I don't define anything? I managed to stretch textures over all the box2d objects (see OP for new image) and it runs smoothly on my pc, mac and xperia. I didn't define how to filter, though. so how is it filtering?

Comment: to define the Filter you just need to take a lookt at the Answer. You give the img or the texture with the `setFilter` method the filter that is used to strech it then.

Comment: Hi BennX yes, I saw that. I meant: what is the Filter if you don't define anything - what is the automatic standard. Thanks

Comment: added some code to my answer so you can find out the default filters.